# Do UDP sockets delineate received data into distinct messages, or does recv read in as much data as possible all at once?

Tags: c++, networking, udp, winsock

Let's say I have a sender application and a receiver application that communicate via UDP.

First, in the sender application, I send some data in two separate calls. First I send these 15 bytes:

`[MYHEADER]hello`

...then, immediately thereafter, I send another 15 bytes:

`[MYHEADER]world`

Now, in the receiver application, I'm listening on the same port with a UDP socket that's bound to the same address. Let's say that both messages have arrived (and in the same order) since the last time I checked the receiver socket.

Here's some pseudo-code that shows how I'm polling the socket for incoming data each frame:

```
uint32 PendingSize;
while (Socket->HasPendingData(PendingSize))
{
    uint32 BytesRead;
    uint8 MessageData[kMaxMessageSize];

    if (Socket->Recv(MessageData, kMaxMessageSize, BytesRead))
    {
        // Do stuff here
        // Will BytesRead be equal to PendingSize?
    }
}
```

`HasPendingData` wraps a call to `ioctlsocket` with `FIONREAD`, returning whether data is waiting in the receive buffer, and populating `PendingSize` with the number of bytes waiting. `Recv` calls `recv` to read that data into a buffer that I can read. If it returns true, then I respond to the data I've received.

Here's my question. Which of these scenarios accurately reflects what would happen in this situation?

**Option A.**

1. `HasPendingData` returns true and shows a pending size of 15 bytes. `Recv` gives me the message `[MYHEADER]hello`.
2. `HasPendingData` returns true and shows a pending size of 15 bytes. `Recv` gives me the message `[MYHEADER]world`.
3. `HasPendingData` returns false.

**Option B.**

1. `HasPendingData` returns true and shows a pending size of 30 bytes. `Recv` gives me the message `[MYHEADER]hello[MYHEADER]world`.
2. `HasPendingData` returns false.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UDP datagrams are individual and self-contained.

`send()` and `sendto()` send a new datagram each time.

`recv()` and `recvfrom()` read a single whole datagram.  If your buffer is too small to receive a given datagram, you will get an `WSAEMSGSIZE` error and that datagram will be lost if you do not specify the `MSG_PEEK` flag.

`FIONREAD` tells you the total number of raw bytes in the socket's receive buffer, not the number of datagrams, or the size of those datagrams.  This is clearly stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573.aspx):

> FIONREAD
>   Use to determine the amount of data pending in the network's input buffer that can be read from socket s. The argp parameter points to an unsigned long value in which ioctlsocket stores the result. FIONREAD returns the amount of data that can be read in a single call to the recv function, which may not be the same as the total amount of data queued on the socket. **If s is message oriented (for example, type SOCK_DGRAM), FIONREAD still returns the amount of pending data in the network buffer, however, the amount that can actually be read in a single call to the recv function is limited to the data size written in the send or sendto function call.**

If you need to check the size of the next datagram, call `recv()` or `recvfrom()` with the `MSG_PEEK` flag.  Once you have deetermined the actual size of the datagram, you can read it without the flag so it is removed from the socket buffer.  Otherwise, just allocate a buffer that is large enough to accommodate the largest datagram you will ever receive, or even just 65535 which is the largest size that UDP supports.

So, to answer your question, what will really happen in your example is **Option A**, except that the first `HasPendingData` will report 30 pending bytes instead of 15.

Comment: Aha, you're right. The problematic part of my code was the assumption that `HasPendingData` (i.e. `FIONREAD`) was giving me size values that reflected the amount of data I'd get from a call to `recv`. When I received the data, I was checking the received size against `PendingSize` and discarding messages in certain cases, meaning that messages were being incorrectly discarded in cases where multiple messages/datagrams were waiting to be read. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, the size reported by `FIONREAD` does not reflect the size read by `recv()` or `recvfrom()`.  For UDP, use `FIONREAD` only as an indication of when to read, not how much to read.  In which case, you can replace `FIONREAD` with `select()` instead.